# Insert IF NOT EXISTS into existing SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restore some data I lost from an SQL file. I'm wondering if it's possible to insert an IF NOT EXIST around all of the data, or certain parts? For example I have over 500 lines of this:

```
INSERT INTO `TOWNY_RESIDENTS` (`name`, `town`, `lastOnline`, `registered`, `isNPC`, `title`, `surname`, `protectionStatus`, `friends`, `townBlocks`, `town-ranks`, `nation-ranks`) 
VALUES
('003497', '', 1345023973086, 1344596322606, 0, '', '', 'residentBuild,residentDestroy,residentSwitch,residentItemUse', '', '', NULL, NULL),
('007belg', '', 1359561715886, 1359561236484, 0, '', '', 'residentBuild,residentDestroy,residentSwitch,residentItemUse', '', '', '', ''),
('00Landmine', '', 1360592736927, 1360592672899, 0, '', '', 'residentBuild,residentDestroy,residentSwitch,residentItemUse', '', '', '', '')
```

Comment: by exist, do you mean the value of the whole columns on both row are the same? on such specific field only?

Comment: Maybe use this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with ignore ?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `TOWNY_RESIDENTS`
(`name`, `town`, `lastOnline`, `registered`, `isNPC`, `title`, `surname`, `protectionStatus`, `friends`, `townBlocks`, `town-ranks`, `nation-ranks`)
VALUES ('003497', '', 1345023973086, 1344596322606, 0, '', '', 'residentBuild,residentDestroy,residentSwitch,residentItemUse', '', '', NULL, NULL)
```